# Deprecated imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins

Tags: flutter, gradle-plugin

I followed [following link](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply) and get now this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: Settings file '../AndroidStudioProjects/xyz/android/settings.gradle' line: 22
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '{agpVersion}', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:{agpVersion}')
Searched in the following repositories:
Google
MavenRepo
Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: {agpVersion}::: that should be a valu and not {agpVersion} which is android gradle plugin now at version 8.2.2'

Comment: thx and what will be the kotlin version ? Or better: where may I find these values ?